# Show custom control hint when disabled

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, vcl

I've written a custom control (`TCustomControl`) which shows the standard built-in hint on hovering. However, when the control is disabled, the hint does not show. But, the `TSpeedButton` does show a hint when it's disabled, so there must be a way I can do the same in my control.

What do I need to do to show hints when my control is disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable the window handle in order to get a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` which starts showing the hint. This has some implications.

First, to enable the window handle (WinAPI), you need to delete the `WS_DISABLED` style from the window style, or use [`EnableWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646291(v=vs.85).aspx). This modification does not synchronize the VCL's `Enabled` property (unlike the other way around: setting the `Enabled` property dóes call `EnableWindow`), which is why this works.

But enabling the window handle lets all mouse messages through, so you have to block them and activate the hint manually on `WM_MOUSEMOVE`:

```
type
  TMyControl = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FDisabledHint: Boolean;
    procedure CheckEnabled;
    procedure SetDisabledHint(Value: Boolean);
    procedure CMEnabledchanged(var Message: TMessage);
      message CM_ENABLEDCHANGED;
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure SetParent(AParent: TWinControl); override;
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  published
    property DisabledHint: Boolean read FDisabledHint write SetDisabledHint;
  end;

{ TMyControl }

procedure TMyControl.CheckEnabled;
begin
  if DisabledHint and HasParent and (not Enabled) and
      not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    EnableWindow(Handle, True);
end;

procedure TMyControl.CMEnabledchanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  CheckEnabled;
end;

procedure TMyControl.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  if DisabledHint and not Enabled then
    Params.Style := Params.Style and (not WS_DISABLED);
end;

procedure TMyControl.SetDisabledHint(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FDisabledHint <> Value then
  begin
    FDisabledHint := Value;
    CheckEnabled;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyControl.SetParent(AParent: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited SetParent(AParent);
  CheckEnabled;
end;

procedure TMyControl.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if not Enabled and DisabledHint and (Message.Msg = WM_MOUSEMOVE) then
    Application.HintMouseMessage(Self, Message);
  if Enabled or (Message.Msg < WM_MOUSEFIRST) or
      (Message.Msg > WM_MOUSELAST) then
    inherited WndProc(Message);
end;
```

I checked the working of the `TabStop` property, and this solution does not interfere with it. But beware of issues which I have not thought of yet.

(Besides, why a disabled `TControl` shows a hint is because it receives a `CM_MOUSEENTER` from `WndProc` of its parent, despite of that same parent blocking all other mouse input via `IsControlMouseMsg` to prevent the mouse events from firing.)

Answer (score 6):

The standard hint mechanism is based on mouse messages.  Controls derived from `TWinControl` (which includes `TCustomControl`) do not receive mouse messages when disabled, and the hint system internally ignores disabled windowed controls.  `TSpeedButton` is derived from `TGraphicControl` instead of `TWinControl`, so it is not subject to those restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you control's Winproc doesn't even get called when you control is disabled. Thy this small demo in order for understainding the message loop a bit better.

Place a TPanel on a form, and add a Double clickEvent To the form. Then try this code:

```
unit Unit39;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

type
  TPanel = class(ExtCtrls.TPanel)
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  end;

  TForm39 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure FormDblClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form39: TForm39;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TPanel }

procedure TPanel.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  Application.MainForm.Caption := FloatToStr(now);
end;

procedure TForm39.FormDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel1.Enabled := not Panel1.Enabled;
end;

end.
```

YES! Correct: Ugly hack and violation of ALL designpatterns but with this small example you can see how the message loop works, and it is a very simple way to test some thing.

PS: I placed this as an answer because you can not format you text in  comment :D